# Clojure & Kafka: how to calculate lag?

Tags: clojure, apache-kafka

I'm using [clj-kafla](https://github.com/pingles/clj-kafka) to build a Kafka consumer using Clojure. I'm trying to find a way to get the lag of a conumer group, just as if I was using the Kafka script `kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker`. Any suggestions?